# Pandas dataframe: how to cluster together groups by values without machine learning?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

print(df)

      A       B         C           D
0     2       0         11          0.053095
1     2       0         11          0.059815
2     0       35        11          0.055268
3     0       35        11          0.054573
4     0       1         11          0.054081
5     0       2         11          0.054426
6     0       1         11          0.054426
7     0       1         11          0.054426
8     42      7         3           0.048208
9     42      7         3           0.050765
10    42      7         3           0.05325

    ....
```

The problem is, the data is naturally "clustered" into groups, but this data is not given. From the above, rows 0-1 are one group, rows 2-3 are a group, rows 4-7 are a group, and 8-10 are a group.

I need to impute this information. One could use machine learning; however, is it possible to do this only using pandas?

Can users groupby the values of the columns to create these groups? The problem is the values are not *exact*. For the third group, column `B` has group 1, 2, 1, 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure pandas solution would involve binning, assuming that your values are close to each other and your bin size is large enough for cluster variation but smaller than distance between cluster values. That answer depends on your data.

The binning approach uses the `cut` function in pandas. You provide a series (or array) and the number of bins you want to the function. The function evenly subdivides the range of your series into the given number of bins and determines where each value in the input falls. The output for the below set of columns will be which bin the value fell in and will be what you can group by, following your original train of thought.

The way this would come out in practice for bins of size ~5 is

```
for col in df.columns:
   binned_name = col + '_binned'
   num_bins = np.ceil(df[col].max()/5)
   df[binned_name] = pd.cut(df[col],num_bins,labels=False)
```

Comment: This may work. However, if I understand correctly, this would have to be applied to multiple columns. Check if there's a cluster with bin +/- on the first column, and then check if this holds for the second column, etc. 

Otherwise, you could end up with multiple clusters within one cluster.

Comment: That would occur if your bin size is too large. You could optimize for finding a 1-d silhouette coefficient but at that point you'd be better off using k-means to respect the multidimensionality of the data.
This answer is to satisfy the condition of using groupby for clusters, so this is a way of feature-engineering your columns.

Comment: Let's say we use bin size +/- 1. Group rows 2-3 and group rows 4-7 will still be clustered into two groups? Even though their values for column A are the same?

Comment: I think this works, but don't you need to compare bins? That is, bin values A and compare with binned values from B. Based on some condition, A is the correct cluster. If not, keep comparing. 
Perhaps I misunderstand your code? Any help/details appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Summary: I think this works, but there are times where I need to cluster by "A_binned". "A_binned" may contains two groups (e.g. all values in A_binned are the same because the values in A are the same---see group rows 2-3 and group rows 4-7). We then need to compare these values to "B_binned". Any ideas?

Comment: The more complexity you add the less useful a pure pandas approach is. The dataframe returned is the same number of rows as the original just with more columns, one bin column for each original column. You can easily group by each one and get the mean + variance to do deeper analysis. But as you try to do advanced clustering it's less clear why you would avoid using a clustering function from a library like Scikit Learn.